# user_id is not showing in firebase audience analytics

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I am trying to create audience in firebase. Since firebase provides user id setter method. I am also using the same method but when i create audience in Firebase, i  am unable to find user_id.
I can see custom dimensions. but not in build user_id.

Anyone suggestion ??

unable to find solution. It seems google has removed to access user_id.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoKpF.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.